# AFNetworking 2.0 update on an existing project

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I recently updated my project to 2.0 of AFNetworking and it appears that the AFHTTPClient file is missing.

I read the following at: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide

It appears i will now have to use AFHTTPRequestOperation ?

If so how can I modify the following piece of code to the new AFHTTPRequestOperation?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL];

        AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
        [client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
        [client postPath:LOGIN_PATH parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.userNameOrEmail.text ,@"userNameOrEmail",self.password.text,@"password", nil]
                 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) 
         {
             bool success = [[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"success"] boolValue];
             NSString *displayMessage = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"displaymessage"];

             if (success) {
                 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                 [defaults setObject:self.userNameOrEmail.text forKey:@"userNameOrEmail"];
                 [defaults setObject:self.password.text forKey:@"password"];

  //              [Flurry setUserID:self.userNameOrEmail.text];
                 [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:displayMessage];
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
             } else {
                 [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:displayMessage];
             }    
         } 
                 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) 
         {

             NSLog(@"error is: %@", error);

             [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:MSG_SERVER_ERROR];
         }];
```

UPDATE: I did the following:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.userName.text ,@"user", self.email.text, @"email",self.password.text,@"password", nil];
        [manager POST:WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            bool success = [[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"success"] boolValue]? @"YES" : @"NO";

            NSString *displayMessage = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"displaymessage"];

            if (success) {
                [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:displayMessage];
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            } else {
                [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:displayMessage];
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:MSG_SERVER_ERROR];
        }];
```

Comment: Your update looks correct; is it working?  If so, you should post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.userName.text ,@"user", self.email.text, @"email",self.password.text,@"password", nil];
        [manager POST:WEB_SERVICE_BASE_URL parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            bool success = [[responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"success"] boolValue]? @"YES" : @"NO";

            NSString *displayMessage = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"displaymessage"];

            if (success) {
                [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:displayMessage];
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            } else {
                [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:displayMessage];
            }
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:MSG_SERVER_ERROR];
        }];
```